# Missing character in Tikz files

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a TeX document with many Tikz files. I am using TeXmaker for editing and compiling my Latex document. In all of my Tikz figures, the figure is plotted, but there is no curve in them and I got lots of these errors:

```
 Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
 Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
 Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont!
 Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
 Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
 Missing character: There is no 9 in font nullfont!
 ...
```

The code is :

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{plain}
\let\labelindent\relax
%\usepackage[draft,inline,nomargin]{fixme}    

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{5cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{7cm}

\newlength\smallfigureheight
\newlength\smallfigurewidth
\setlength\smallfigureheight{5cm}
\setlength\smallfigurewidth{7cm}

\newlength\largefigureheight
\newlength\largefigurewidth
\setlength\largefigureheight{6cm}
\setlength\largefigurewidth{8cm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}



%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=Figure/]

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}          % for highlighting comments
\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage{easy-todo}

%\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother
\newcommand{\paragraphX}[1]{\vskip 4pt \noindent \textbf{#1} \hskip .05in}
%\newenvironment{smitemize}
%  {\begin{list}{$\bullet$}
%     {\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
%      \setlength{\leftmargin}{10pt}
%      \setlength{\topsep}{-7pt}
%      \setlength{\labelwidth}{5pt}
%      \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}}}
%  {\end{list}}


\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\renewcommand{\enumerate}{
  \oldenumerate
  \setlength{\topsep}{-7pt}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=0.5cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello World}

% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Anonymous}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Anonymous}}




\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\makeatletter\def\@IEEEpubidpullup{9\baselineskip}\makeatother
\IEEEpubid{\parbox{\columnwidth}{Permission
}
\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{}}


% make the title area
\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}

\begin{axis}[
ylabel={rate},
xmin=0, xmax=20,
ymin=0, ymax=0.1,
axis on top,
width=0.82\figurewidth,
height=0.78\figureheight,
xtick={0,5,10,15,20},
xticklabels={$0$,$5$,$10$,$15$,$20$},
ytick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1},
yticklabels={$0.00$,$0.02$,$0.04$,$0.06$,$0.08$,$0.10$},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(-0.42,0.97)}},
%legend pos=outer north east,
legend style={font=\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont},
legend entries={{$\alpha$ = 0.9},{$\alpha$ = 0.8}},
%legend cell align={left}
]
\addplot [very thin, red, mark=*, mark size=3, mark options={solid,draw=black}]%1
table {%
1 1.1
3 3.2
5 4.3
7 3.6
10 3.33
15 3.2
20 3.9
};
\addplot [very thin, green!50.0!black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}]%2
table {%
1 2.1
3 2.2
5 2.3
7 3.3
10 3.4
15 3.5
20 3.6
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{{\bf Selection:} Users.}
        \label{fig:ci}
\end{figure*}

%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\bibliography{refs}
%\appendix
%\input{appendix}
\end{document}
```

I think latex skips all the digits in the `\addplots` that causes no curve in the figures.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! In your shrunken code you should add the preamble as well, not just a code snippet.

Comment: But I already can see a mistake in your code: you're opening with `\addplot table { ... ` and closing with `... ];` which is wrong. You should use curly brackets there, not square ones.

Comment: @Alenanno, Sorry my bad those were curly buckets, I fixed, and added the preamble

Comment: Dear MOH, not on such way :-(.  Please, merge all of your code snippets in one, small but complete document (Minimal Working Example: MWE), which we can compile and which will show your problem.

Comment: Please note, that the legend entries (and similar cases in your document) should be typed as `$\alpha=0.0$, high` (eq. and value in math too) to get the right spacing of the equal sign ;-)

Comment: @Zarko, thanks, Now it is in single snippet,

Comment: The “missing character” warnings are a side effect of how TikZ processes its code; they're irrelevant for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You are plotting all of the `y` values against `x=0`, aren't you? If you vary the value of `x`, you get a result (though maybe not the particular result you want):

[image: plot]

[How can probability exceed 1?!]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{5cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{7cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.75,0,0.75}
  \definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={stream},
    ylabel={Cumulative probability},
    xmin=0, xmax=303,
    ymin=0, ymax=0.0162,
    axis on top,
    width=1.3\figurewidth,
    height=1.2\figureheight,
    xtick={30,90,150,210,270},
    xticklabels={Mar,May, July,Sept,Dec},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    mark repeat={10},
    ytick={0,0.002,0.004,0.006,0.008,0.01,0.012,0.014,0.016,0.018},
    %yticklabels={0.000,0.002,0.004,0.006,0.008,0.010,0.012,0.014,0.016,0.018},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    %legend pos=outer north east,
    legend pos=south east,
    legend entries={{$\alpha$=0.0, low},{$\alpha$=0.0, high}},
    legend cell align={left}
    %legend columns=-1,
    %legend to name=named1
    %legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east}
    ]
    \addplot[thick, blue, mark=triangle*, mark size=3, mark options={solid,rotate=180,draw=black}]
    table  {%
      0 0
      40 0.000333333333333333
      80 0.000333333333333333
      120 0.000666666666666667
      160 0.000666666666666667
      200 0.001
      240 0.001
      280 0.00133333333333333
    };
    \addplot[thick, blue, mark=triangle*, mark size=3, mark options={solid,rotate=180,draw=black}]
    table {%
      0 0
      40 0.000333333333333333
      80 0.000333333333333333
      120 0.000666666666666667
      160 0.000666666666666667
      200 0.001
      240 0.001
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited the code, it does not work.

Comment: Check my code works. Then gradually add subtract stuff from your example to find the source of the problem. Right now, there's a bunch of irrelevant stuff in your code which has nothing to do with the problem and is just making it difficult for you to diagnose it.

Comment: I need those parts for the rest of document

Comment: @MOH I'm not suggesting you delete them from your document. Make a copy. You are trying to find the source of a problem. You want to ignore all the stuff which doesn't cause it in order to find it. It is like knowing there's a rotten apple in the basket: take out all the good ones until you find it. You might say 'but I need those good apples!'. Yes. Don't throw them away. Set them aside.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is still with your data. Every point you are plotting is off the chart because `y` exceeds `ymax`.

Comment: You're right, I'll try it step by step

Comment: @MOH It is just that your y values are off the scale in this case. I can't reproduce the complaints about null font with your code.

Comment: why y values? ymax  = 0.0162 and all y values are less than this

Comment: @MOH In your new code, they are not less. That's why your code doesn't show a plot.

Comment: I changed the y values, but it returns error: ! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file

Comment: @MOH Since I have no idea what code you are now trying to compile, I can't possibly know what is wrong. Are you loading the values from a file? Is the file in your working directory? Does it have any strange characters in the name (e.g. spaces)?